# Regarding state of stack

Tags: c, function, gdb, stack

I have a program for which I wanted to understand the state the stack will be during its execution. My sample program is simple enough,

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
   setuid(0);
   system("/bin/bash");
   return 1;
 }
```

Now when I debug this program with gdb I get the address of setuid() function but when I look at the stack I am not able to figure its address.

My stack's state after starting to execute main(),

```
Ajai@ubuntu:/tmp$ gdb -q mal
Reading symbols from /tmp/mal...done.
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483fd: file mal.c, line 2.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/mal 

Breakpoint 1, main () at mal.c:4
4        setuid(0);
(gdb) x/32xw $esp
0xbffff3a0:    0x0015ed35    0x0011ea50    0x0804842b    0x0028bff4
0xbffff3b0:    0x08048420    0x00000000    0xbffff438    0x00145e37
0xbffff3c0:    0x00000001    0xbffff464    0xbffff46c    0x0012e414
0xbffff3d0:    0xffffffff    0x0012cff4    0x08048243    0x00000001
0xbffff3e0:    0xbffff420    0x0011da31    0x0012dad0    0xb7fffb48
0xbffff3f0:    0x00000001    0x0028bff4    0x00000000    0x00000000
0xbffff400:    0xbffff438    0xb68cac87    0x61d0d5f8    0x00000000
0xbffff410:    0x00000000    0x00000000    0x00000001    0x08048340
(gdb) p setuid
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x1c8ee0 <setuid>
```

Am I looking at the stack wrong ?

I also wanted to know how will the address of setuid() function call and its parameter and system() function call and its parameter will be stored in the stack when main() function starts to execute.

I am sorry if this kind of question has already been asked but I could not find one.

Comment: The address of the function may not be in the stack at all.  It is needed in the code; it is not needed in the stack.  The return address inside `main()` will be on the stack when in a function called from `main()`, but that's different from the address of `main()` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is exceedingly unclear, likely because you do not understand how stack and calls work and interact.

Somehow you are expecting to find the address of setuid on the stack before that function has been called. But that address wouldn't be there at all (neither before the call, nor while the call is in progress, nor after it has finished).

If you set a breakpoint on `setuid` itself, run to that breakpoint, and examine the stack. Then, you'll see the address in `main` (not of `main` itself, but of the instruction in `main` that follows the CALL instruction that got you into `setuid` in the first place).

> I assume this is how stack looks like when execution is about to go to setuid() function (assuming I have a breakpoint at setuid function call)
>
> 1.call to setuid()
>
> 2.return address to be reached after setuid() function call
>
> 3.parameters to setuid() function.

As I said, your assumptions are incorrect: there is *no* "call to setuid" on the stack (but 2. and 3. are correct).

Comment: Ok I will try to put my question a little clear. In stack if a function call is made say in this case setuid() I assume this is how stack looks like when execution is about to go to setuid() function (assuming I have a breakpoint at setuid function call)


  

     >1.call to setuid()
    
      2.return address to be reached after setuid() function call           
    
      3.parameters to setuid() function.

Am I right?

Comment: This isn't exactly clearer, but I think you really confuse what is on the stack. Program execution is controlled by the code segment (cs register), which you can look into with the EIP pointer. Addresses of calla are typically in registers; which one, you see by single stepping through the assembly. The stack is sort of a temp storage for local variables and function parameters. So yes, you'd find (3) on or near a stack, but not (1) or (2) (except by two you mean the old ESP/EBP, but I doubt that. I think you mean the line following the old EIP.

Comment: If what I write makes no sense to you, I really suggest grabbing any book on this. The old "Hacking. The art of exploitation." is, while dated, on such questions excellent if you've never done this.

Comment: Well the old EIP is actually saved on the stack, but you need to process stack information etc more clearly and i warmly suggest the above book, or any free online source, or this will keep confusing you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I got it. I was struck with someother problem and was confusing it with others. I now got what you are saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As ER points out, single step through the assembly instructions. The address of the function called is usually put into the EAX register prior to function call. Check that, or whatever else your compiler puts it in.